# How to check if tables refreshed in Bigquery or not?

Tags: hive, google-bigquery

Currently I have around 1000 tables in which I need to track around 500 tables in various bigquery datasets and generate a report or create of dashboard.so that we can monitor and act promptly if a table is not refreshed.

Could someone please tell me how can I do that with minimal usage of Bigquery slots.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to query the last modification time as shown here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-metadata

You could then add a table with the max allowed time interval for a table to be updated and include that table in the query to create your own alerts.

drftr

Answer (score 1):

There is a Preview feature [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS](http://INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS) giving you the `LAST_MODIFIED_TIME` per table in a dataset

```
select *
from yourDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS;
```